# LocationListener with Geocoded Toast not stopping once activity leaves "OnCreate"

Tags: android, gps, lifecycle, toast, locationlistener

I have a simple locationListener that is using GPS only to start.  Inside OnLocationChanged I do a geocode lookup and display a Toast message.  The problem is once the activity is no longer in front the gps is still receiving updates and processing the Toasto.  I have RemoveUpdates in onStart, onPause, onDestroy and onStop.

Any idea why I can't get this service to stop?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mc = mapView.getController();

    locationListener = new GPSLocationListener(); 
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);           
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);    

...
...       

public void onStart(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    locationManager=null;
}

public void onPause(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    locationManager=null;
}

public void onDestroy(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    locationManager=null;
}

public void onStop(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    locationManager=null;
}

class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener {     
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {

          current_heading=location.getBearing();
          String current_bearing = headingToString2(location.getBearing());

          point = new GeoPoint(
              (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
              (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

          // add marker
          MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
          mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);
          List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
          listOfOverlays.clear();
          listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

          mapView.setStreetView(showStreet);
          // enable to show Satellite view
          mapView.setSatellite(showSatellite);        
          // enable to show Traffic on map
          mapView.setTraffic(showTraffic);        
          mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

          mc.animateTo(point);
          mc.setZoom(16);

          address = ConvertPointToLocation(point);
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), address, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), address, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).cancel();
          }     
    }
```

Here is the LogCat when attempting to go home

```
12-28 16:41:51.402: ERROR/LocationMasfClient(577): reverseGeocode(): GLS failed with status 20
12-28 16:41:51.423: INFO/NotificationService(577): enqueueToast pkg=com.kuli.example.android511 callback=android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@4375d1f0 duration=1
12-28 16:41:53.272: DEBUG/LocationMasfClient(577): getAddressFromProtoBuf(): Ignore feature 0,Lyndon Station
12-28 16:41:53.282: INFO/NotificationService(577): enqueueToast pkg=com.kuli.example.android511 callback=android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@43711b70 duration=1
12-28 16:41:55.533: DEBUG/dalvikvm(633): GC freed 715 objects / 92504 bytes in 324ms
12-28 16:41:57.883: INFO/ActivityManager(577): Starting activity: Intent { action=android.intent.action.MAIN categories={android.intent.category.HOME} flags=0x10200000 comp={com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher.Launcher} }
12-28 16:41:57.932: DEBUG/LocationManager(1191): removeUpdates: listener = com.kuli.example.android511.android511$GPSLocationListener@43762f40
12-28 16:41:57.952: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1191): Shutting down VM
12-28 16:41:57.952: WARN/dalvikvm(1191): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)
12-28 16:41:57.966: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1191): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-28 16:41:57.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1191): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.kuli.example.android511/com.kuli.example.android511.android511} did not call through to super.onPause()
12-28 16:41:57.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2830)
12-28 16:41:57.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2797)
12-28 16:41:57.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
12-28 16:41:57.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:112)
12-28 16:41:57.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1191):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1699)
12-28 16:41:57.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1191):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-28 16:41:57.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1191):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-28 16:41:57.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
12-28 16:41:57.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1191):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-28 16:41:57.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1191):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-28 16:41:57.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1191):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
12-28 16:41:57.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1191):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
12-28 16:41:57.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1191):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 16:41:57.992: INFO/Process(577): Sending signal. PID: 1191 SIG: 3
12-28 16:41:57.992: INFO/dalvikvm(1191): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
12-28 16:41:58.133: INFO/dalvikvm(1191): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-28 16:41:58.442: WARN/ActivityManager(577): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{437b5170 {com.kuli.example.android511/com.kuli.example.android511.android511}}
12-28 16:43:08.393: DEBUG/dalvikvm(631): GC freed 9811 objects / 553776 bytes in 104ms
```

Comment: hmmmmm, I wonder if I need to set locationListener=null; as well?

Answer (score 2):

You're not overriding any methods.

```
public void onStart(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    locationManager=null;
}

public void onPause(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    locationManager=null;
}

public void onDestroy(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    locationManager=null;
}

public void onStop(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    locationManager=null;
}
```

Those aren't the method signatures for those methods. It should be

```
@Override
protected void onStart(){

}
```

etc

You should get used to adding the `@Override` annotation to methods that you're overriding

Comment: You're probably getting an IllegalArgumentException http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates%28android.app.PendingIntent%29. You have to post the error from your logcat to help anymore.

Comment: The message tells you exactly what the problem is. You have to call `super.onStart()` as the first thing in your `onStart()` method

Comment: It's pretty clear you haven't gone through the basic android tutorials. You should do that, these are fundamentals things that you should know.

Comment: Actually I have, I was surprised the app worked at all without an onStart().  And I was merely asking a question, no need to question what I do/do not know.

Comment: @Kuli: It's perfectly acceptable to not override any of the other activity lifecycle methods other than onCreate()

Comment: Thanks Falmari - BEEN A LONG DAY!  I think I follow the logic of what was happening.  By @Override onPause I was suspending the listener but what actually happened is I had it in multiple methods, onPause covers when the application leaves focus, whether it dies or not.  I had it in more than one method and those were causing the issue :(

Comment: Yup. You can only call removeUpdates() once for each listener added.